# How do I navigate to a new URL instead of appending the new URL to my current URL

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express

I want to link to a different website however the link constantly just gets added to the current websites link. Instead of going to https://superbalist.com/men/tops/shirts/relaxed-fit-short-sleeved-linen-blend-shirt-black/1185650 it just goes to http://localhost:5173/men/65742939603f5f1a461521b7/https://superbalist.com/men/tops/shirts/relaxed-fit-short-sleeved-linen-blend-shirt-black/1185650

````
const navigateToItemWeb = () => {
    navigate("https://superbalist.com/men/tops/shirts/relaxed-fit-short-sleeved-linen-blend-shirt-black/1185650");
  };```


I've tried parsing it as a new URl how ever it still persists.
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window.location.href like

```js
const navigateToItemWeb = () => {
  window.location.href = "https://superbalist.com/men/tops/shirts/relaxed-fit-short-sleeved-linen-blend-shirt-black/1185650"
}
```